# remove image sizes from media uploader box

Tags: wordpress

I have used custom image sizes in wordpress with "add_image_size" and it's working fine.

I tried to remove default image sized with following code:

```
function filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']); 
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'filter_image_sizes');
```

But these default images sizes are still visible in media upload popup.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may give it a try

```
function my_custom_image_sizes($sizes) {
   unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
   unset( $sizes['medium']);
   unset( $sizes['large']);
   unset( $sizes['full'] ); // removes full size if needed

   // add your image sizes, i.e.
   $myCustomImgsizes = array(
          "magazine-thumb" => __( "Magazine" ),
          "slideshow-thumb" => __( "Slideshow" ),
          "sidebar-thumb" => __( "Sidebar" )
   );
   $newimgsizes = array_merge($sizes, $myCustomImgsizes);
   return $newimgsizes;
}
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_image_sizes');
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on 3.5.1 in my `localhost`

Using `unset` and `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` will work but only on images uploaded after the function is added. To change it for existing images you need to regenerate them using a plugin ( in essence deleting that image size) or just hide that option from being visible.

```
// add custom image size
function mytheme_95344() {
        add_image_size('x-la',800,800, false);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_95344' );

// remove it
function remove_image_size_95344($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['x-la']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_image_size_95344');
```

So this `x-la` size will still show for images before the `unset` function was added.

To remove this you can try.

Hide it from the display using `image_size_names_choose`

```
function remove_image_size_95344($possible_sizes) {

 unset( $possible_sizes['x-la'] );
 return $possible_sizes;

}  
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'remove_image_size_95344');
```

Answer from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95344/hide-custom-image-sizes-from-media-library#answer-95350

Answer (score 0):

I tried  `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` and it wasn't working, so I inspected the  `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` function and saw that they now use the  `intermediate_image_sizes` filter hook.

[image]

So I was able to remove all image sizes by doing this.

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes', function($size){
    return [];
},9999);
```

Fill free to create the callback function separately so it can be unhooked.